# Part time among full timers

Tags: salary

I am the only part time engineer paid hourly at my workplace. Sometimes I work 30 hours, sometimes 50+. Anything over 40 is 1.5 times hourly rate. So sometimes I  get paid more than my supervisor. I am getting pressure to go full time on salary. Can I be forced into a full time position if I want to stay hourly? I get all benefits, holidays, bonus, and every hour I work I'm compensated for. I don't want to end up salaried and forced to donate time like others do.

Comment: "Can I be forced into a full time position if I want to stay hourly?" without a jurisdiction, there is no way for us to answer that. Please add a location tag, if your labor laws and customs vary by federal state, also add the federal state in the text of your question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your decision should be only yours. If you feel that you wanted to be a full time only then change your position or else don't bother yourself for others. You should've think of your benefit and most importantly inner peace. Time is money! Moreover if you are working part time then you can do whatever you want after you finish your job. Only doing job is not something that you wanted to do in your life. On your spare time you may do something that you like (i.e: hobbies).

Answer (score 5):

So work out your current annual remuneration and negociate the salary they should pay you.

If what they offer in terms of salary is too low, then you have two basic options:

1. Stay with the current arrangement,
2. Find another post elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Under pressure to do something is not the same as being forced to do something. Is it peer pressure or has management intimated or stated that they would like you to change to full time?

I would suggest you check your contract of employment to see if there is a clause which obliges you to change to full time if a position became available.

Check with HR how secure your position is under your current terms as some employers may consider part-time staff to be temporary rather than full-time and permanent.

Also consider that you may be eligible for additional benefits as a full time employee rather than part time, at the cost of being more flexible with your time (in your company's favour).